# Tabs based on CSS Grid don’t show proper content

Tags: javascript, html

I'm setting up a JS based tab navigation but somehow the Tab content doesnt show properly.
The idea is to only show the Tab content of the active state.

I just want the Tab Content to show that belongs to the tab.

[image]

The Code looks like this:

```js
        function setupTabs () {
            document.querySelectorAll(`.tabs_button`).forEach(button => {
                    button.addEventListener('click', () => {
                        const sideBar = button.parentElement;
                        let tabsContainer;
                        tabsContainer = document.querySelector(`section`);
                        const tabNumber = button.dataset.forTab;
                        const tabToActivate =
                            tabsContainer.querySelector(`.tabs_content[data-tab='${tabNumber}']`);

                        sideBar.querySelectorAll('.tabs_button').forEach(button => {
                            button.classList.remove("tabs_button--active");
                        });

                        tabsContainer.querySelectorAll(`.tabs_content`).forEach(tab => {
                            tab.classList.remove("tab_content--active");
                        });

                        button.classList.add("tabs_button--active")
                        tabToActivate.classList.add("tabs_content--active")

                    });
                });
        }
        document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
            setupTabs();
        });
```

```css
        * {box-sizing: border-box}

        .wrapper{
            display: grid;
            grid-template-columns: 150px 1fr;
            border:1px solid #cccccc;
            padding: 15px;
            margin: 0 auto;
            grid-template-areas:
                'nav main '
                'nav main'
        }

        .tabs_sidebar {
            grid-area: nav;
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: column;
            background: #cccccc;
        }

        section {
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: row;
            flex-shrink: 0;
            min-height: 400px;
        }
        .tabs_content {
            grid-area: main;
            background: #f6e3e3;
            padding-left: 15px;
            font-size: 1rem;
            display: none;
        }

        .tabs_button {
            display: block;
            padding: 10px;
            background: #eeeeee;
            border: none;
            width: 100%;
            outline: none;
            cursor: pointer;
            font-size: 1rem;
        }
        .tabs_button:active {
            background: #dddddd;
        }
        .tabs_button:not(:last-of-type){
            border-bottom: 1px solid #cccccc;
        }
        .tabs_button--active {
            font-weight: bold;
            border-right: 3px solid #009879;
            background: #dddddd;
        }
        .tabs_content--active {
            display: block;
        }
```

```html
    <div class="wrapper">
        <nav class="tabs_sidebar">
            <button class="tabs_button tabs_button--active" data-for-tab="1">Tab #1</button>
            <button class="tabs_button" data-for-tab="2">Tab #2</button>
            <button class="tabs_button" data-for-tab="3">Tab #3</button>
        </nav>

        <section id="main_con" class="tabs_content tabs_content--active">
            <div class="tabs_content tabs_content--active" data-tab="1">
            <h2>Tab #1</h2>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,  </p>
             </div>

            <div class="tabs_content" data-tab="2">
            <h2>Tab #2</h2>
            <p>Nunc vel risus  </p>
            </div>

            <div class="tabs_content" data-tab="3">
            <h2>Tab #3</h2>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor </p>
            </div>
        </section>

    </div>
```

I cannot find the error. Any help is much appreciated.

merci in advance

A

Comment: it might be useful to see the CSS that goes with this

Comment: Are you using display property or not for hiding elements for example using display:none in tab_content class and display:block !important in tab_content--active class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please notice that you have a typo.

You can modify this line:

```
tab.classList.remove("tab_content--active");
```

to this:

```
tab.classList.remove("tabs_content--active");
```

and it will work as expected for toggling the xxxx-active class for the clicked button and its corresponding data tab.

Answer (score 0):

I modified the classnames used as I was getting confuzzled by the similar names. I think this is perhaps inline with what you were hoping to achieve?

```js
function setupTabs() {

    const clickhandler=function(e){
        const tabsContainer = document.querySelector('section.tabs_content');
        const tabToActivate = tabsContainer.querySelector('[ data-tab="'+this.dataset.forTab+'" ]');



        this.parentNode.querySelectorAll('.tabs_button').forEach( button => {
            button.classList.remove('tabs_button--active');
        });

        tabsContainer.querySelectorAll('div').forEach( tab => {
            tab.classList.remove('active');
        });

        this.classList.add('tabs_button--active')
        tabToActivate.classList.add('active')   
    };

    
    
    document.querySelectorAll( '.tabs_button' ).forEach( button => {
        button.addEventListener('click',clickhandler);
    });
}
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',setupTabs);
```

```css
* {box-sizing: border-box}

.wrapper{
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 150px 1fr;
    border:1px solid #cccccc;
    padding: 15px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    grid-template-areas:
        'nav main '
        'nav main'
}

.tabs_sidebar {
    grid-area: nav;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    background: #cccccc;
}

section {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-shrink: 0;
    min-height: 400px;
}

.tabs_content {
    grid-area: main;
    background: #f6e3e3;
    padding-left: 15px;
    font-size: 1rem;
    display: block;
}

.tabs_button {
    display: block;
    padding: 10px;
    background: #eeeeee;
    border: none;
    width: 100%;
    outline: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 1rem;
}
.tabs_button:active {
    background: #dddddd;
}
.tabs_button:not(:last-of-type){
    border-bottom: 1px solid #cccccc;
}
.tabs_button--active {
    font-weight: bold;
    border-right: 3px solid #009879;
    background: #dddddd;
}




.tabs_content > div{display:none;}
.tabs_content > .active{display:block;}
```

```html
<div class='wrapper'>
  <nav class='tabs_sidebar'>
    <button class='tabs_button tabs_button--active' data-for-tab='1'>Tab #1</button>
    <button class='tabs_button' data-for-tab='2'>Tab #2</button>
    <button class='tabs_button' data-for-tab='3'>Tab #3</button>
  </nav>

  <section id='main_con' class='tabs_content'>
  
    <div class='active' data-tab='1'>
      <h2>Tab #1</h2>
      <p>Content Tab1</p>
    </div>

    <div data-tab='2'>
      <h2>Tab #2</h2>
      <p>Content Tab2 </p>
    </div>

    <div data-tab='3'>
      <h2>Tab #3</h2>
      <p>content Tab3 </p>
    </div>
    
  </section>
</div>
```